# Tridion Powertools 2013 sp1 installer throws Error 1001

Tags: powertools

when I try to install the PowerTools on a 2013 sp1 environment I get the following error:
[image]

Is anyone familiar with this error and how to fix this?

When I run the installer with logging this is a part of the output where it goes wrong:

```
MSI (s) (84:F8) [12:56:34:899]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (84:A0) [12:56:34:899]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (84:A0) [12:56:34:899]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (84:A0) [12:56:34:914]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (84:A0) [12:56:34:914]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (84:A0) [12:56:34:914]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (84:A0) [12:56:34:914]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (84:A0) [12:56:34:914]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (84:A0) [12:56:34:914]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (84:A0) [12:56:34:961]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (84:5C) [12:56:34:961]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (44:A0) [12:56:34:961]: Back from server. Return value: 1603
MSI (c) (44:A0) [12:56:34:961]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (44:A0) [12:56:34:961]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 12:56:34: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (44:A0) [12:56:34:961]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 12:56:34: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 12:56:34: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (44:A0) [12:56:34:961]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
Action 12:56:34: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
```

(full version available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwulhvOApefecXpXM0hXYi10T2c/view?usp=sharing))

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you try running the installing with logging and see what that leads to? Example: msiexec /i "PowerTools 2013 SP1.msi" /L*V "C:\powertools-install.log"

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated my question with the output of the log.

Comment: Could you check if you have the "IIS Management Compatibility" server role installed on the machine?

Comment: It would also help if you could post the entire log file (or make it available somewhere, if you think it's too big for the question)

Comment: Full version of the log is available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwulhvOApefecXpXM0hXYi10T2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Wow, Peter thank you! Installing the "IIS Management Compatibility" was the solution :) How can I mark your answer as the solution?

Comment: Glad to hear it (especially because I couldn't find anything useful in that log file)! I've formally submitted it as an answer so you can accept it. Sorry for the inconvenience, by the way (I created that installer :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please ensure that you have installed the "IIS Management Compatibility" server role on your machine. This is needed to modify the Tridion website to add the virtual directories for the PowerTools editor and model.

Comment: Indeed. Works. http://serverfault.com/questions/469388/install-iis-6-management-compatibility-on-iis-8-windows-2012

Comment: Does Powertools work with Web 8? I have not been able to get it to work within my instances..

Comment: No, there is no version of the PowerTools for Web 8. I don't foresee one in the near future either. There hasn't been much activity on it lately. Personally, I'm thinking about creating individual Alchemy plugins for some of them instead...